# Atomic symlink replacement windows c# throws IOException "This application does not support the current operation on symbolic links"

Tags: c#, .net, windows

The goal is to update a symlink target atomically. All of my research says that the only way to do this is to create a new symlink with new target then delete/replace old symlink. File.Replace() throws IOException "This application does not support the current operation on symbolic links". I am currently using native "kernel32.dll" for symlink creation. Any advice as how to go about update/replacement of old symlink with new would be a huge help.

```
if (File.Exists(oldSymlink))
{
    // Create temp symlink to replace old link
    var replacementSymlinkFile = "path/to/newLink"; 

    CreateSymbolicLink(replacementSymlinkFile, newTargetFile, 0)

    File.Replace(replacementSymlinkFile, oldSymlink, null); // throws SYSTEM IO ERROR This application does not support the current operation on symbolic links
}
```

Comment: This needs a better temporary name than hard-coded "NewLink". Anyway, .NET Core has [`Move(String, String, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_Move_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_), which allows replacing the destination. Or call WINAPI [`MoveFileExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw) with `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING`.

Comment: If `oldSymlink` targets a directory, the new symlink will need to be created with the flag `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: I've edited the snippet, "NewLink" value was just to be concise, actual value is a file path. This is a file to file symlink and WINAPI MoveFileExW seems to have done the trick! Thanks so much @ErykSun been trying to get this working all day.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Eryk Sun , using MoveFileExW() method from native "kernel32.dll" allows one symlink to be replaced with another. I did not get a chance to try .NET Core Move() method since I am using the native dll already I went with the former option. Thanks!